# What Javascript if/else statement can return an enlarged image to its default size?

Tags: javascript

I am new to this website and to coding in general. I am having trouble attempting to get an image to shrink back to its "small" size after being enlarged by a single click.

This is my HTML element:

```
<img src="http://image.com/123.jpg"
id="smart_thumbnail"
class="small"
```

This id and class cannot be changed, as it is for an assignment. The "small" class automatically turns the image into a thumbnail. It enlarges upon clicking, but I cannot get it to return to its "small" state by clicking it again. It must be done with an if/else statement.

Here is the Javascript template given:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");
    thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
        thumbnailElement.className = "";

    });
});
```

The double quotes is the "enlarge" class.

Thank you, and I apologize if this post does not fit the format required on this site. I also searched everywhere for this solution but could not find it for the life of me.

Comment: I didn't get the `enlarge` part, but what you are probably looking for is a way to **toggle** a class. You could use `classList.toggle` for that.

Comment: Or if you HAVE to use an if/else use classList.contains to check if the element has the class and then remove it, or vice versa

Comment: @QuentinVeron the double quotes is what allows it to "enlarge", apparently by removing the "small" class upon clicking the image. This is merely my guess. Deleting that line of code removes the ability to enlarge the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the [DOM classList attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
thumbnailElement.classList.toggle("small");
```

This will remove the `small` class from the element if it is present, otherwise it will add it.

Comment: Thank you. Another question I have is, where about do I add this line in? A rookie question, yes. Also, is there an if/else equivalent in case this is considered a workaround by my peers?

Comment: Just put it inside your event listener, instead of `thumbnailElement.className = "";`. Also, an if/else version would be `if (thumbnailElement.classList.contains("small"){ thumbnailElement.classList.remove("small"); }else{ thumbnailElement.classList.add("small"); }`.